# How to merge two pandas dataframe and sort by number record in the dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Now ,i have two pandas dataframes

The rule is:
When the "no" are the same of the both dataframe,
just fetch the "pass" result record to the df1 dataframe.

When the "no" are different of both dataframe,
According to number size merge the dataframe of df2 into the df1.

The both of dataframe 1 and 2 is below:

```
====df1====
   no result
0  12   pass
1  13   fail
2  15   pass
3  16   pass
4  17   fail

====df2====
   no result
0  13   pass
1  14   fail
```

The expected answer is:

```
====df1-merge====
   no result
0  12   pass
1  13   pass
2  14   fail
3  15   pass
4  16   pass
5  17   fail
```

But after performing my code, the result is below, How can I fix my code to the same of the above expected answer?
Thanks

```
====df1-merge====
   no result
0  12   pass
1  13   pass
2  15   pass
3  16   pass
4  17   fail
```

my code as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lst11 = [12,13,15,16,17]
lst12 = ["pass","fail","pass","pass","fail"]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst11,lst12)), columns = ['no','result'])

lst21 = [13,14]
lst22 = ["pass","fail"]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst21,lst22)), columns = ['no','result'])
print("====df1====")
print(df1)
print("====df2====")
print(df2)


for i in range(len(df1) - 1):
    no1 = df1.at[i, "no"] 

    for x in range(len(df2)):
        no2 = df2.at[x, "no"]
        if no1 == no2:
            result_no1 = df1.at[i,'result'] 
            result_no2 = df2.at[x,'result']  
            #==============================
            if result_no1 == "pass":
                result_no1_str = 1
            else:
                result_no1_str = 0

            if result_no2 == "pass":
                result_no2_str = 1
            else:
                result_no2_str = 0
            #==============================
            result_all = result_no1_str or result_no2_str
            #==============================
            if result_all == 1:
                result_all = "pass"
            else:
                result_all = "fail"
            df1.at[i, "result"] = result_all 

      
        else:
            
            if no1 < no2:  
                if i == len(df1) - 1: 
                    no = df2.at[x,'no'] 
                    result = df2.at[x,'result'] 
                    df1.loc[len(df1.index)] = [no, result]  

                else: 
                    pass

                
            else: 
                if i == len(df1) - 1: 
                    no = df2.at[i,'no'] 
                    result = df2.at[i,'result']               
                    df1.loc[i+1] = pd.Series({"no": no,"Result": result}) 
                else:
                    pass
                

print("\n====df1-merge====")
print(df1)
```

***[===== NEW EDIT after adding the result type of "N/A"   =====]***

If the result type have "N/A", not just "pass" and "fail"...
and the rule is:

When the "no" are the same of the both dataframe,
just fetch the "pass" result record to the df1 dataframe.

but if one of result is "N/A", first select "pass", then "fail",
if both result are "N/A", then select "N/A"

When the "no" are different of both dataframe,
According to number size merge the dataframe of df2 into the df1.

```
The both of dataframe 1 and 2 is below:
====df1====
   no result
0  12   pass
1  13   fail
2  15   pass
3  16   N/A
4  17   N/A
5  18   pass

====df2====
   no result
0  13   pass
1  14   fail
2  15   N/A
3  16   N/A
4  17   fail
```

The expected answer is:

```
====df1-merge====
   no result
0  12   pass
1  13   pass
2  14   fail
3  15   pass
4  16   N/A
5  17   fail
6  18   pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df1.copy()
df.loc[df["no"].isin(df2["no"]), "result"] = "pass"
df = df.append(df2[~df2["no"].isin(df["no"])], ignore_index=True)
```

Note : Here I resetted the index of the resulting dataframe to avoid duplicate indexes

**EDIT:** To work with NA values, it will be much simpler to set the no column as the index of the dataframe (i.e. by creating the dataframe like this : `df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=lst12, index=lst11, columns=["result"])` )

Then you can add an extra condition to only modify the result column of your first dataframe when values in both dataframe are not na.

```
df = df1.copy()
df.loc[df.index.isin(df2.index) & (~(df2["result"].isna() & df["result"].isna())).reindex(df.index), "result"] = "pass"
df = df.append(df2[~df2.index.isin(df.index)]).sort_index()
```

Comment: If you sort the number column as well as resetting inse the solution will be completed. Great effort..

##Code
df = df.sort_values('no').reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: Thanks for both help!!
I never thought the code is simplified after use pandas module! 

I originally planned use some loop with if...else, 
but look like the pandas module more simply! 

But, If add the new type of result (N/A), it still can use the pandas module to process?
((I don't know write another question in the comment, so I add the new question as above in the question field))

Comment: @wasicat I edited the answer with a solution for your edited question.